# Access layers attributes from layer name

Tags: javascript, extjs, openlayers-3

Let's say i have this layer with a few attributes (id, x, y, z, year1, etc.):

```
var receptors1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    name: "Layer Name 1",
    visible: true,
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: "url.json",
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    })
});
```

I have a dropdown button in my app which allow the user to select a layer name from the loaded layers. Tied to this form, I have a button which needs to get the info about the layer name selected by the user and show its attributes in a new dropdown button.

I'm wondering how to access the attributes by starting at the Layer name level.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

To access what you need, you need to follow this logic: layer --> source --> features --> for each one --> attributes (known as properties).  Here's an example:

```
receptors1.getSource().getFeatures().forEach(function(feature) {
    console.log(feature.getProperties());
    // you can also get each one individually, for example:
    console.log(feature.get('year1'));
}, this);
```